# java : Use Server-Side Encryption in Amazon S3 using vfs s3 plugin

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For copying file in S3, I am using *vfs-s3-2.2.1.jar* 
I found *S3FileObject* class under *com.intridea.io.vfs.provider.s3* package.
In which I am using `public void copyFrom(final FileObject file, final FileSelector selector)` method for copy file.
In this method I found following code :

```
try {
    if (srcFile.getType().hasChildren()) {
        destFile.createFolder();
        // do server side copy if both source and dest are in S3 and using same credentials
    } else if (srcFile instanceof S3FileObject) {
        S3FileObject s3SrcFile = (S3FileObject)srcFile;
        String srcBucketName = s3SrcFile.getBucket().getName();
        String srcFileName = s3SrcFile.getS3Key();
        String destBucketName = destFile.getBucket().getName();
        String destFileName = destFile.getS3Key();
        CopyObjectRequest copy = new CopyObjectRequest(
                srcBucketName, srcFileName, destBucketName, destFileName);
        if (srcFile.getType() == FileType.FILE && getServerSideEncryption()) {
            ObjectMetadata meta = s3SrcFile.getObjectMetadata();
            meta.setSSEAlgorithm(AES_256_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION);
            copy.setNewObjectMetadata(meta);
        }
        getService().copyObject(copy);
    } else if (srcFile.getType().hasContent() && srcFile.getURL().getProtocol().equals("file")) {
        // do direct upload from file to avoid overhead of making a copy of the file
        try {
            File localFile = new File(srcFile.getURL().toURI());
            destFile.upload(localFile);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // couldn't convert URL to URI, but should still be able to do the slower way
            super.copyFrom(file, selector);
        }
    } else {
        super.copyFrom(file, selector);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new FileSystemException("vfs.provider/copy-file.error", new Object[]{srcFile, destFile}, e);
} catch (AmazonClientException e) {
    throw new FileSystemException("vfs.provider/copy-file.error", new Object[]{srcFile, destFile}, e);
} finally {
    destFile.close();
}
```

[In official reference it uses these method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/sse-c-using-java-sdk.html)

```
withSourceSSECustomerKey(sseKey)
withDestinationSSECustomerKey(newSseKey);
```

In *copyFrom* method of *vfs-s3-2.2.1.jar* *S3FileObject* 
I can't find any method to set **SSECustomerKey**
How can I achieve the same.
Thanks for looking here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not test but I look at the lib/code quickly - in https://github.com/abashev/vfs-s3/blob/branch-2.3.x/src/main/java/com/intridea/io/vfs/provider/s3/S3FileSystemConfigBuilder.java there is a method to set the server-side encryption

```
/**
 * use server-side encryption.
 *
 * @param opts The FileSystemOptions.
 * @param serverSideEncryption true if server-side encryption should be used.
 */
public void setServerSideEncryption(FileSystemOptions opts, boolean serverSideEncryption)
{
    setParam(opts, SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION, serverSideEncryption);
}
```

so before you're calling the `copyFrom` you can do

```
    S3FileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().setServerSideEncryption(
        S3FileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance().getFileSystem().getFileSystemOptions(), 
        true);
```