# Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Encryption Keys (SSE-C) with using vfs s3 plugin

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3

I am using vfs s3 plugin to perform file related operation in S3.
Official guide for  Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Encryption Keys (SSE-C) is here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/sse-c-using-java-sdk.html but I am using vfs s3 plugin.

I have checked code of `copyFrom` method in `S3FileObject` in `com.intridea.io.vfs.provider.s3` package but I didn't found any code to implement **Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Encryption Keys (SSE-C)** There is option for set 
[Server Side Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35891632/java-use-server-side-encryption-in-amazon-s3-using-vfs-s3-plugin) but how can achieve it with **Customer-Provided Encryption Keys**

Is there only way to modify code of s3 plugin? or there is any other way to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it is not possible to use customer-provided encryption keys with vfs-s3 library but I can take your PR or need some time to implement it - you are first one who have asked for it.